# Ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth paired but not listed as an output device

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

Bluetooth is enabled.  I can pair, this seems to work out of the box.  If this much is supported in Ubuntu by default, should the connected device be available for audio?  I'm looking at "Sound Settings" in the "Output" tab where it says "Play sound through."  I see only my speakers.

I have ran Ubuntu updates recently, this seems to be an ongoing bug.  Any help in resolving this in the distribution would be much appreciated.

```
apt-get install blueman
blueman is already the newest version.
```

...

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:2098 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:5754 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 024: ID 05f3:0007 PI Engineering, Inc. Kinesis Advantage PRO MPC/USB Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 023: ID 05f3:0081 PI Engineering, Inc. Kinesis Integrated Hub
Bus 002 Device 022: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 046d:c063 Logitech, Inc. DELL Laser Mouse
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 026: ID 04f9:0013 Brother Industries, Ltd Printer
Bus 002 Device 028: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

...

```
pactl list short
0   module-device-restore       
1   module-stream-restore       
2   module-card-restore     
3   module-augment-properties       
4   module-switch-on-port-available     
5   module-alsa-card    device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_03.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
6   module-alsa-card    device_id="1" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
7   module-udev-detect      
8   module-bluetooth-policy     
10  module-native-protocol-unix     
11  module-default-device-restore       
12  module-rescue-streams       
13  module-always-sink      
14  module-intended-roles       
15  module-suspend-on-idle      
16  module-systemd-login        
17  module-position-event-sounds        
18  module-filter-heuristics        
19  module-filter-apply     
20  module-x11-publish  display=:0  
21  module-x11-bell display=:0 sample=bell.ogg  
22  module-x11-cork-request display=:0  
23  module-x11-xsmp display=:0 session_manager=local/jcalfee-Inspiron-7548:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1577,unix/jcalfee-Inspiron-7548:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1577  
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
5   2   83  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
6   2   83  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
0   module-systemd-login.c  (null)
2   protocol-native.c   indicator-sound-service
6   module-x11-xsmp.c   (null)
7   protocol-native.c   unity-settings-daemon
9   protocol-native.c   python2.7
20  protocol-native.c   unity-settings-daemon
25  protocol-native.c   skype
49  protocol-native.c   unity-settings-daemon
50  protocol-native.c   chromium-browser
83  protocol-native.c   unity-control-center
94  protocol-native.c   pactl
0   audio-volume-change s16le 2ch 44100Hz   0.067
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0  module-alsa-card.c
1   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0  module-alsa-card.c
```

Comment: Are you using Blueman?  [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/645226/edit) your question to include the results in terminal for `lsusb; pactl list short`

Answer (score 0):

I notice one thing missing from the `pactl list short` results

```
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then redo the pairing and see if the device shows in sound settings

Comment: result of that is simply `Failure: Module initialization failed` (I'm in ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Please ask your own question and include the results of `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a`